# How to make lebel Invisible / Visible based on the Input given in the Search TextBox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm searching names using a text box which are auto fillable.  When I enter the name other than the list of auto fillable one's, I need to display a label dynamically like **"Please Enter a Valid Name"** like that. If I remove my wrong entry in the test box, then label should be invisible.

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbName" caption="Enter Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator  runat="server" ID="UIRequiredFieldValidatorName"
            ControlToValidate="tbName" />

        <asp:Button ID="UIButtonGo" runat="server" Text="Search" />
        <asp:Label ID="UILabelSearch" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </p>
```

Please let me know the possible ways for this one. Thanks

Comment: you can use the `pattern` attrib to police, as well as the `list` attrib to make hits easier.

Comment: can you please provide me something in the code format plsss

Comment: oh, nevermind, i didn't realize you weren't talking about html...

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do this in JavaScript. Handle the onchange event and check textbox value against the auto fillable values. In your code add tbName.properties.add("onchange","validatorMethod(this);");. In JavaScript file add:      [image]